# Dspace 4.2 to 5.x what choose?

Tags: java, repository, dspace

I'm working with Dspace 4.2, but i need upgrade to version 5. What version it's more recommended 5.2 or 5.4?  Which is the most stable?

Comment: I would use the latest release (5.4 is a bug-fix release); using an older version just invites the question of when do you upgrade to 5.3 or 5.4?

Comment: You has complemented the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSpace 5.4 is a stable release with more bug and security fixes than 5.2 so I would recommend 5.4.

[The DSpace releases page](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/releases) so you can compare the versions yourself.

*Remember, [Google](https://www.google.com) is your friend.*

Comment: Yes, I researched the matter and found that in many forums, users recommended version 5.2.

Comment: I asked also for some universities and many of them me recommend version 5.2 to upgrade.

Comment: @BrendowAdriel Have you checked the date the forum messages were posted? Version 5.4 may not have been the latest stable build at the time. Anyways, the latest stable build is the version you want, unless it's missing  something your current build has; and this is a security and bug fix build which makes it all the better to choose.